# Stuck on old kernel when trying to upgrade from Squeeze to Wheezy

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, dpkg

I have both 3.2 and 2.6 installed on a server, but neither `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` nor `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64` can upgrade the kernel.

```
user@server:~$ uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Tue May 13 18:41:58 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

user@server:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)
Release:    7.11
Codename:   wheezy

user@server:~$ sudo apt-cache policy linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64
linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:
  Installed: 3.2.89-2
  Candidate: 3.2.89-2
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.89-2 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.78-1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages

user@server:~$ sudo apt-cache policy linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64
linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64:
  Installed: 2.6.32-48squeeze6
  Candidate: 2.6.32-48squeeze6
  Version table:
 *** 2.6.32-48squeeze6 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Here's the last couple of lines from dpkg.log

```
2017-08-03 15:05:39 install linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:amd64 <none> 3.2.89-2
2017-08-03 15:05:39 status half-installed linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:amd64 3.2.89-2
2017-08-03 15:05:43 status unpacked linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:amd64 3.2.89-2
2017-08-03 15:05:44 status unpacked linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:amd64 3.2.89-2
2017-08-03 15:05:44 startup packages configure
2017-08-03 15:05:44 configure linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:amd64 3.2.89-2 <none>
2017-08-03 15:05:44 status unpacked linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:amd64 3.2.89-2
2017-08-03 15:05:44 status half-configured linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:amd64 3.2.89-2
2017-08-03 15:05:55 status installed linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:amd64 3.2.89-2
```

Comment: It looks like 3.2 is installed, what did you expect to happen? Installing one kernel does not remove the old one, it just adds a new kernel, which is what you want, that way you can pick which one to boot into in case of problem. Once it's confirmed that the new one works, you can remove the old one. Note that it's possible that some post or pre install scripts for 2.6 kernel did not correctly handle the 3.x syntax. Reboot, select in the advanced grub configs, assuming you use grub, the new kernel, and if you don't see it, there could be some further glitches due to the changed kernel syntax.

Comment: I assume you're moving from squeeze to wheezy so you can then upgrade to stretch, which you want to do since old stable will reach end of life very soon.

Comment: I'd expect grub to boot into wheezy's default kernel, 3.2. Isn't it supposed to do that? I'm looking at what I've got it set to and it says "default"

Comment: There were a lot of problems with old scripts when the switch from 2.6 to 3.2 happened, a lot of them assumed that 2.6.x would just go on forever, so didn't actually handle the switch to 3.x, which was handled of course by the new software and scripts. So it could well be the old logic failed to handle the 3.x kernel. Note that you are installing to old stable, again, which is not a great idea since it will be EOL I think in 6 months? I can't remember how long they keep old stable updated after new stable comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hosting provider doesn't use the normal Debian grub setup where GRUB_DEFAULT is declared in the file `/etc/default/grub`. For me, I had to manually edit the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and change the `default` directive to `0`.

Make sure to ask your host if they've got an alternative setup for grub.

Comment: That's GRUB 1 (GRUB legacy). I guess we all assumed you were using GRUB 2, since GRUB 1 is ancient. And how come your hosting provider decides what system you have installed? That's very strange.

Comment: it's probably https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/PvGrub

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of handling this in general is to install the metapackage `linux-image-amd64`.

```
 apt-get install linux-image-amd64
```

Replace by the appropriate arch if you are not running `amd64`. This will install the correct default kernel for your release.

And to address your current issue, GRUB will usually boot with the top entry in the menu. Is this where your 3.2 entry is?

You could check `/etc/default/grub`, where `GRUB_DEFAULT` is normally set to 0. I.e.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

To quote the GRUB documentation:

> 'GRUB_DEFAULT'
>        The default menu entry.  This may be a number, in which case it
>        identifies the Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero,
>        or the title of a menu entry, or the special string 'saved'.  Using
>        the id may be useful if you want to set a menu entry as the default
>        even though there may be a variable number of entries before it.

And the current stable is stretch, not wheezy, so use that.

Comment: The default is being saved to `/boot/grub/default`, but just in case, I created a file for `/etc/default/grub` and set `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`. Still nothing appears to change. Looking inside the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst` it says that I've got `Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64` at the top of the default options.

Comment: And yes, i have the linux-image-amd64 meta package installed.

Comment: @Andrew I don't see a `/boot/grub/default`. Did you add that file? And `3.2.0-4-amd64` is the correct default kernel for Wheezy, so I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen. Is the problem that your GRUB menu is not booting you into `3.2.0-4-amd64`? Please be clear about what problem you are seeing. Also, can you paste the output of `dpkg -C` into the question , please?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I see you wrote in the comments "I'd expect grub to boot into wheezy's default kernel, 3.2. Isn't it supposed to do that? I'm looking at what I've got it set to and it says "default"". That should be added to the question, not a comment, since it is apparently your main question. Please edit your question appropriately.